# some way to put noindex and nofollow on the link's comment of the wordpress

Tags: seo, wordpress

I am having many commentators on my site that are placing links, I would like to put noindex and nofollow on all links, i already searched a lot on the internet but didn't find anything, anyone know any function or plugin that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Nofollow , WordPress 1.5 and above does this automatically.  Maybe the rest of that page will help.

Answer (score 0):

What is your wordpress site? Is it self-hosted by wordpress and you are a free user, or you have installed it on your host? It is very easy, use a javascript for any comment. Details are beyond this comment, but it is very easy to search for any  tag on the inserted text and change the desired attribute.